# Angular 7 @input property 'selected' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular. I want to ask about `@Input("data") detailData = {};` in angular. When I `console.log(detailData)` it come out data like this.

> Object { category: "dictionary", entityCategory: null, iconName: "dictionaryD", detail: {…}, key: "dictionary-7" }

And When I click button in  `console.log(detailData)` it display like this

> > Object { category: "dictionary", entityCategory: null, iconName: "dictionaryD", detail: {…}, key: "dictionary-7", selected: true }

It mean, when I click button it add `selected: true` but when I `console.log(detailData.selected)` it come out

> error TS2339: Property 'selected' does not exist on type '{}'.

What whould I do to make it work when I `console.log(detailData.selected)` it not come out error.

**Add Component Code**

```
    export class ResultDetailsComponent implements OnInit {


      @Input("data") detailData = {};
      @Output() expand = new EventEmitter();
      private expanded = false;
      constructor() {}
    // console.log(this.detailData)
      ngOnInit() {

       console.log(this.detailData)}
        if (detailData) {

          detailData.scrollIntoView()
         }
}
```

**Note:**
But in **HTML** page when I `{{detailData.selected}}` it come out `True`

Hope you all can help me.

Comment: @Input() detailData : any;

Comment: @rosiejaneenomar Thanks for your comment.. When I change to `@Input() detaiData : any` when console.log it come out `undefined`

Comment: can you share your component how it is being bind.

Comment: @rosiejaneenomar I've share my component code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is just related to the type of `detailData` , when you set the `detailData` property without define the type of it typescript will inferred the type base of the value like `a = 10` type of a will be a number but in here you set the value a empty object without any property so the type will inferred as empty object without any property set the type to any `detail Data : any = {}` will solve the problem or you can create an interface base of your structure or a class and at the declaration instantiate new object.

set the type to any

```
@Input("data") detailData : any = {};
```

set type to interface

```
export interface DataDetail {
  category?: string
  entityCategory?: string,
  iconName?:string, 
  detail?: any, 
  key?:string, 
  selected?:boolean
}
```

*component*

```
@Input("data") detailData : DataDetail = {};
```

Comment: @Pravu happy to help 

Answer (score 0):

you can try use `console.log(detailData['selected'])`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But it come out `undefined`